# TabItem icon not showing with Material Components 1.1.0

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-tablayout, material-components-android

Just upgraded my application to Material Components 1.1.0 and the icons in my TabLayout no longer display.
I followed the tutorial on the official website of google material.io, the preview in Android Studio is good, but once the application is launched, the icons do not appear.

Here is the **XML Code** :

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="center">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_fav"/>

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"/>


        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my **styles.xml** file I defined *colorPrimary* and *colorOnPrimary* which are used to tint icons and TabLayout background color.

However, even if the preview in Android Studio is good, once the application is launched, the background of my TabLayout is displayed in the right color, but the icons don't show up.

**EDIT :**

Just use debug mode and icon of tabs are null for each tab item :

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I have found the problem but not the solution!
The problem comes from this line :

```java
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

After this line is executed, all icons in TabLayout are reset to null.
By disabling this line I have all of my icons.
However, how can i setup a ViewPager with icons on my TabLayout ?
If I set them up manually, I will not have the color inherited from MDC

Comment: upload your styles.xml files too

Comment: I've already done it, it inherits from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: what are values for colorPrimary and colorOnPrimary ?

Comment: `<color name="colorPrimary">#00838f</color>` & `<color name="colorOnPrimary">#ff8f00</color>` I dont know how this could help you

Comment: The code seems fine to me ... I tried they displayed properly...

Comment: Post your code pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager()` removes all tabs and then adds tabs from the adapted.
To add the icons you can use something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(iconResId);
}
```

> If I set them up manually, I will not have the color inherited from MDC

The `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`uses by default the `Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout` style. If you want to override the icon tint just use `tabIconTint` in your layout or custom style:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
  app:tabIconTint="@color/my_selector"
  ...>
```

Comment: When doing this, will it take into consideration the style of the TabLayout on the icons and their tint?

Comment: @mamenejr the viewPager doesn't change the tabLayout style.

Comment: @mamenejr normal behaviour by google about the style or about the viewPager?

Comment: ViewPager disabling icons on TabsLayout